# No HDMI audio between Dell Inspiron N4050 laptop to LG 50PJ350 TV

Tags: laptop, hdmi, dell-inspiron, lg-monitor

Video output is perfect, however I can't see any options for the audio.

I have gone to the Dell website and updated both the audio and the video drivers but still do not see a HDMI option when going to Playback Devices in my sound options. I have both display disabled and disconnected options ticked.

Comment: Do you have one that says "Digital Audio"?  That's what it is on my computer.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, I only have speakers/headphones :(

Comment: Do you have integrated or dedicated graphics?  I am not sure the Intel HD 3000 supports audio over HDMI, so if you have only the integrated - you may be SOL. (Though I am researching more to confirm).

Comment: Intergrated. It uses the IDT HD Audio codec. Thinking I am SOL :)